# Проектирование реляционной базы данных (mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Возникла проблема, заключается она в том, что мне совершенно никак не может прийти в голову, как организовать и связать несколько таблиц в БД.
Имеется информационная система, условно говоря для учебного заведения.
Есть таблицы со студентами, пользователями (преподаватели и т.д), группами, кафедрами и учебными предметами.

Необходимо организовать расписание занятий для каждой группы, взяв предметы из соответствующей таблицы. В голову не приходит лучше идеи, чем *связать через один ко многим* и создать промежуточную таблицу. Но в таком случае будет необходимо несколько таблиц для каждого дня недели или же для каждой группы, к тому же отсутствует разграничение и форматирование данных в таблицах.

Может кто реализовывал систему с подобного рода архитектурой и может подсказать в какую сторону двигаться?

UPD

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

departments - кафедры,
academic_subjects - предметы,
users - пользователи,
roles - права

Comment: добавь структуру в виде DDL таблиц, которые ты уже представляешь, как сделать, и что именно ты собираешься включить в «расписание», а то я не особо видно в чём проблема...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Расписание хотелось бы организовать таким образом, чтобы была таблица, в которой для каждой группы, была своя строка с данными, содержащая расписание для каждого учебного дня в течении, допустим, семестра. Составлялось расписание исходя из имеющихся предметов в таблице academic_subjects

Comment: на будущее,  данные лучше добавлять в виде текста, по возможности. Проще читать, можно копировать, нет дополнительных вопросов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Необходимо организовать расписание занятий для каждой группы, взяв предметы из соответствующей таблицы. … Но в таком случае будет необходимо несколько таблиц для каждого дня недели или же для каждой группы.

Когда возникает создать отдельную таблицу для какой-то сущности, то обычно вместо этого надо просто добавить ещё одно поле в единую таблицу. Кроме того о таблице не стоит думать, как о неком едином «расписании», а скорее как о наборе неких занятий/лекций. В результате получается что-то вроде такого:

```
CREATE TABLE lectures (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY, -- суррогатный ключ
  group_id INT,
  academic_subject_id INT,

  -- день недели и время
  day_of_week ENUM ('...', 'sat', 'sun' ), -- день недели; в моём мире их всего 3
  lecture_num INT, -- номер временного слота лекции (1,2,3...)

  FOREIGN KEY (group_id) REFERENCES groups(id)),
  FOREIGN KEY (academic_subject_id) REFERENCES academic_subjects(id))
);
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, помог. Насчет DDL понял.)